# dotnetcore 3.1 webapi with Microsoft.Identity.Web that both validates user and app tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

TLDR: WebApi migrated from ADAL to MSAL does no longer work when called by another API with direct permissions. (Yet, it does work when using on behalf tokens.) Link to a minimal example at the bottom.

Recently I started to migrate some dotnet API’s from ADAL to MSAL. Some of these API’s are called directly from frontends others are used by other API’s. In the calls to the API’s there are the bearer tokens present in the headers, normal stuff. We use two types of tokens:

1. User/on behalf of tokens and;
2. Application tokens, tokens derived from the application identity.

The API’s make use of the current latest version of Microsoft.Identity.Web. In our case it does both the validation of the tokens and the creation of new tokens. We noticed that in the case of user/on behalf tokens, everything works as expected. However, for application tokens we are noticing some odd things. In this case we are noticing in particular that it does not pass a “RequireAuthenticatedUser” policy check (default dotnetcore 3.1) on the controllers.

Both tokens use the same audience and both tokens are derived from the same app registration in AD. So it does not feel like a configuration issue.

A workaround that doesn’t feel right: we noticed that if we override the “OnTokenValidated” that is set by Microsoft.Identity.Web, and only let it fire normally in the case of a user/on behalf of token,  we experience no issues.

This finding is peculiar since it is the “OnTokenValidated” event that fires. The token has apparently been validated. The principal has an identity and a user which also has claims and has a “IsAuthenticated” flag that is set to true. But after the function chain that is present through the dependency injection something happens that makes the user invalid an removes the claims that where present through the token.

I have create a minimal example application that demonstrates the issue. See https://github.com/tychok/tokenissues, the only thing you will have to do is set “ClientId” and “Audience” in “appsettings.json” with your own id’s.

In this example apptokens do work due to some peculiar code in ” Startup.cs” from line 43 to 54. If that code is not present apptokens will receive a 401, while user tokens continue to work.

The questions are:

1. Is there something wrong with our approach to the validation to the tokens?
2. What can we do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check : In case of confidential client flows for the app where tokens are requested with no user , then this User information will be null.
You can check the [available flows Acquiring Tokens · GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-Tokens)

In the controller methods, protected web APIs needs  to verify that the token that has to be used to call them  has the right scope or permissions  : using the `[RequiredScopes]` attribute: [Web APIs · AzureAD. GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apis)

- when APIs  called on behalf of a user `scopes` are used
- and when called by daemon applications `app roles` are used

*ex:*

```
[Authorize]
[RequiredScope(HomeController.scopeRequiredByAPI)
public class HomeController : Controller
{
 public const string[] scopeRequiredByAPI = new string[] { "access_as_user" };
  /// ...
  public async Task<IActionResult> Action()
  {
 ...
  }
}
```

If you are requesting `app only tokens`, use **`AddInMemoryTokenCaches`**. For  user tokens, consider distributed token cache. [Token cache serialization (MSAL.NET) - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=aspnetcore)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
   ...
   services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration)
              .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                  .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
   ...
  }
```

Also check if the token is from right endpoint. Try changing accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2  for v2 enpoint of issuer and null or 1 otherwise

[image]

Also in case of static permissions that are required in adal i.e; v1.0 maybe inlarge number and some may not be approved by users .

**References:**

1. [Web APIs · AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apis)
2. [AcquireTokenSilentAsync using a cached token· GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, a couple of days ago i already did find the solution to my problem. And as you also describe in your answer it indeed has to do with the Scopes. For usertokens the scope was already in place, but for app tokens i had created a role and assigned that in the api permissions. But i did not add the admin consent on it. That was why it did not work for me in particular. Your awnser describes it in a bit more detail. but commes down to the same.